# Single CSS stylesheet across many UiBinders in different packages

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I have a GWT 2.4 application which has many UiBinders within different client packages, set out the same as below:

- com.xxx

  - project.gwt.xml
- com.xxx.client

  - entrypoint.java
  - stylesheet.css
- com.xxx.client.package1

  - Page1.java
  - Page1.ui.xml
  - stylesheet.css
- com.xxx.client.package2

  - Page2.java
  - Page2.ui.xml
  - stylesheet.css
- com.xxx.client.package3

  - Page3.java
  - Page3.ui.xml
- war

  - index.html
  - global_stylesheet.css

In my ui.xml files I am having to reference the stylesheet.css file which is within the same package as the UiBinder. I've been trying to reference the global_stylesheet.css file but am having no luck. Ideally I would like to be able to still use the {style.xxx} method of applying a style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a central ClientBundle with a CssResource for `@Source("global_stylesheet.css")`, and reference it from your UiBinder templates:

```
<ui:with type="mypackage.client.MyClientBundle" field="myClientBundle"/>
```

So you can use it like:

```
<g:Label addStyleNames="{myClientBundle.myCssResource.example}"/>
```

But you would have to put global_stylesheet.css somewhere in your classpath - otherwise it cannot possibly be compiled.

Also, don't forget to call ensureInjected() on your CssResource.